# Swiper slider autoplay проблема в мобильном отображении

Tags: javascript, swiper, mobile

Происходит скачок по сайту вверх на высоту слайдера при каждой смене слайда. Когда слайдер в пределах видимости - все ок, но когда находишься на других частях слайда начинает прыгать. Слайдер находится внизу страницы. Отказаться от автопрокрутки нельзя.
Ссылка на видео, как это выглядит - https://drive.google.com/file/d/1yZ5a1huxqmr-TFVLKSCO4oSbmosaTjiB/view?usp=sharing

```
let myImageSlider = new Swiper('.image-slider', {
    navigation: {
        nextEl: '.swiper-button-next',
        prevEl: '.swiper-button-prev'
        },
    pagination: {
        el: '.swiper-pagination',
        },
    simulateTouch: true,
    touchRatio: 1,
    touchAngle: 45,
    grabCursor: true,
    slideToClickedSlide: false,
    hashNavigation: {
        watchState: true,
    },
    slidesPerView: 3,
    watchOverflow: true,
    spaceBetween: 30,
    slidesPerGroup: 1,
    centeredSlides: false,
    initialSlide: 0,
    slidesPerColumn: 1,
    loop: true,
    loopedSlides: 0,
    freeMode: true,
    autoplay: {
        delay: 4000,
        stopOnLastSlide: true,
        disableOnInteraction: false
    },
    speed: 800,
    direction: 'horizontal',
    effect: 'slide',
    breakpoints: {
        320: {
            slidesPerView: 1,
        },
        480: {
            slidesPerView: 2,
        },
        992: {
            slidesPerView: 3,
        }
    },
    preloadImages: false,
});
```

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Answer (score 0):

Данная неприятность исправляется стилем overflow: hidden для контейнера слайдера.